# Display ACF Repeater Fields on Child Pages

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to display the results of an ACF repeater field on child pages. An example of the current code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('recommended-properties') ): ?>
  <?php while ( have_rows('recommended-properties') ) : the_row(); ?>
    <?php the_sub_field('recommended-properties-title'); ?>
    <?php the_sub_field('recommended-properties-description'); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now, I thought I may be able to store the parent page ID in a variable and use that the same way you can get values from another post (see: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/)

I tried the following:

```
<?php $parentPageId = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID ); ?>
<?php if( have_rows('recommended-properties', echo $parentPageId;) ): ?>
  <?php while ( have_rows('recommended-properties', echo $parentPageId;) ) : the_row(); ?>
    <?php the_sub_field('recommended-properties-title'); ?>
    <?php the_sub_field('recommended-properties-description'); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But no luck unfortunately. Any suggestions for where I can go from here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need add echo when you add parameter in function

try below code

```
<?php $parentPageId = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID ); ?>
<?php if( have_rows('recommended-properties', $parentPageId) ): ?>
  <?php while ( have_rows('recommended-properties', $parentPageId) ) : the_row(); ?>
    <?php the_sub_field('recommended-properties-title'); ?>
    <?php the_sub_field('recommended-properties-description'); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: And you should remove ";" after $parentPageId when using it in the function call

Comment: Thanks Luka, I fixed that.